# Setting up swan DVR mobile

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, dvr, browser-plugin

I need help setting up my swan DVR, specifically connecting it to my router. The main issue is in the network setup, it asks for a media port (default 09000) and a web port (default 00080). I'm not sure wether to configure these somehow.

I can connect to the devices IP using the local device ip, but I get a page that reads "You haven't installed the plugin or it's not the latest version, Please click download to install the latest version, Please restart safari after plugin installation", the file I download is "SurveilClient.dmg" (which I'm not sure what to do with).

If I can get it to work locally I'm pretty comfortable with port forwarding to allow access from non-local networks.

Finally, I am currently running a 64 bit windows 7 operating system, so the safari error threw me slightly.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Google chrome, also tried in IE8.

Comment: I have added appropriate tags. Btw, you should really enable Windows Update.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone else that is having this problem, here are some of the things I have done to resolve it (that seem to work) after installing the plugin/add on.

1. Ensure local account is Administrator (or part of group)
2. Tested in Chrome/Firefox & Internet Explorer
3. Installed, Restarted Machine.
4. Right Click both Chrome & Firefox and ran as Compatibility Mode with Administrator Access and Windows 7

These things seem to get it working for me on a Windows 10 machine. Might help, might not. Just offering.

Answer (score -1):

Add the IP or address to compatibility settings in IE.  This always works for me.

Good luck and I hope this helps others.

Comment: As of current form, this is a very short post. Could you please flesh out your answer, why this work, how to add the IP to compatibility settings, and such?